# How to remove port from docker container?

Tags: docker

Currently container port config looks as follows:

```
Ports: {
   "22/tcp": [
       {
           "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
           "HostPort": "9922"
       }
   ],
   "443/tcp": null,
   "80/tcp": [
       {   
           "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
           "HostPort": "9980"
       }
```

I want to stop container 80 port to beign forvarded to host 9980 port.
How to delete this record?

Comment: Stating the obvious, but Wouldn't it be simpler to start a new container? Are you trying to dynamically re-assign the port?

Comment: It would help to give some information how this docker container started. Is it running in daemon mode if so remove corresponding sections ie: "-p 9922:22" restart the script if it is built with dockerfile remove the corresponding "EXPOSE" lines and rerun the container.

Answer (score 1):

Once a container is started you cannot change this. By default, no port is open in Docker and there is only two ways to open them :

- Describe explicitly in Dockerfile the ports to be opened : `EXPOSE 9980`
- Define at creation of the container (CLI, docker-compose, ...) the port binding

So if you need to change the behaviour of the ports container, the easiest way is to change the port bindings and use something like `80:9980` at **creation**.